# setting enemy movement speed to less than 1

Tags: java, int, double, game-physics

In the game that I'm creating I want the zombies to be twice as slow as the player put I don't want to set the players movement speed to 2 because it moves way to fast then. This is the code that controls the zombies speed:

```
Zombie z = (Zombie) zombie.get(i);
if(z.getY() > player.getY()){
        z.setY(z.getY() - 1);
}
if(z.getY() < player.getY()){
        z.setY(z.getY() + 1);
}
if(z.getX() > player.getX()){
        z.setX(z.getX() - 1);
}
if(z.getX() < player.getX()){
        z.setX(z.getX() + 1);
}
```

I have tried to use `(int) .5f`, `(int) .5` and `1 / 2` but all of them makes the zombie stand completly still.

Comment: What variable types are your Zombie x and y fields? They should be double, not int, and the set and get methods should accept and return the same. Note that `(int) 0.5` and `1/2` ***are*** in fact 0. Don't cast here, but again use doubles.

Comment: Or, alternatively, just update the zombies coordinates every other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is to declare your Zombie's x and y fields as doubles, not ints, and thus the `setX(...)` and `setY(...)` methods would accept double and the `getX()` and `getY()` return doubles. If you need int values for your imaging then you can either cast or round the values at the time that this is needed, or give Zombie methods to do this, `getIntValueX()` and `getIntValueY()`.

Also you could just use a single Point2D.Double field in place of your x and y fields.

Answer (score 3):

.5 and 1/2 aren't integers. Math 101. You can't cast a float as an int just by putting an `f` after it. Try removing the `(int)` cast.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with this problem.
But it's just a simple issue.

for example:

```
private int x = 100;
private float speed = 0.5f;

x += speed;
```

this will increase the x position by a float but the x value is an integer so it automaticly rounds off 
the float so it'll be 0

#### solution:

```
private float x = 100;
private float speed = 0.5f;

x += speed;
```